# Change Columns in Page Viewer Web part

Tags: column, iframe, page-viewer-web-part

I have a Page Viewer web part that points to a specific folder in a SharePoint library. Is there a way to change the columns displayed? For instance, can the column "Type" be removed? Can other columns be added?

edit: The Page Viewer points to a FOLDER, not a WEB PAGE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Page viewer web part works by displaying the specified page inside an Iframe, so whatever it displays is just the content of the original page you point it to.

This means that to change the displayed columns, you can just change the all items view of your library by following

> Go to library page > from the above ribbon > select modify view >
>   check and uncheck the columns that you need

Comment: The page viewer web part is displaying a "windows explorer" view, not a SharePoint page. Your suggestion doesn't work when the iFrame displays a folder view.